# How to use jupyter in existing django project

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook

i followed the instruction on the internet to access django apps in jupyter.

I tried 2 ways:

1: created a jupyter file and add the django settings to it like below

'''

```
import sys, os
print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
import django
print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.append('D:/VSCODE/GPOSSYS')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
if 'setup' in dir(django):
        django.setup()
```

'''

> ```
>  1 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
>  2 if 'setup' in dir(django):
>  3     django.setup()
>  File d:\\VSCODE\\GPOSSYS\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py:24, in
>  setup(set_prefix)
>  20 if set_prefix:
>  21     set_script_prefix("/" if settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is None else settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME)
>  24 apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>  File d:\\VSCODE\\GPOSSYS\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\apps\\registry.py:83, 
>  in Apps.populate(self, installed_apps)
>  78 # An RLock prevents other threads from entering this section. The
>  79 # compare and set operation below is atomic.
>  80 if self.loading:
>  81     # Prevent reentrant calls to avoid running AppConfig.ready()
>  82     # methods twice.
>  83     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
>  84 self.loading = True
>  86 # Phase 1: initialize app configs and import app modules.
>  RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
> ```

2:  I installed jupyter, Django-extensions, added it to settings in installed apps and ran python manage.py shell_plus --notebook in the terminal
this is the response i got

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\VSCODE\GPOSSYS\.venv\Lib\site
>     packages\django_extensions\management\commands\shell_plus.py", line 281, in 
>       get_notebook
>         from notebook.notebookapp import NotebookApp
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'
> CommandError: Could not load shell runner: 'IPython Notebook'.
> ```

Both are using the same venv

Is there another way or did i make a mistake somewhere. Thank You

Comment: Try looking at [Use Django in Jupyter](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/use-django-in-jupyter/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u Alias Cartellano for the link

here are the link

1. https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/use-django-in-jupyter/